# How to find the Fourier transform when it is in the form of \$\frac j\pi\$ [\$\frac{1}{(t-3)^2-1}+\frac{1}{(t+3)^2-1}\$]

Tags: fourier

So as the title suggests, I can compute Fourier transforms in basic forms using the known properties. But how would one attempt to do this? How do I compute the integral? Or is there a pattern/pair that I could use? The equation is as follows x(t)= \$\frac j\pi\$ [\$\frac{1}{(t-3)^2-1}+\frac{1}{(t+3)^2-1}\$]

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think I ever heard of a time response that has complex numbers in it. Where does this example come from?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen there is nothing stopping you having a complex time domain signal. This is the case in tomography, for example, wherein two real domain signals are combined into a complex domain signal. Another example is waves in conductors: Maxwell’s equations have the same solutions as in vacuum, but with complex numbers. The Fourier transform won’t have symmetric amplitude, if the time domain is complex. As for the question, it looks like two time shifted trig signals in Fourier space.

Comment: @user110971 What you're talking about is the physical separation of what would be a complex signal, which implies, physically, two real paths. So, in OP's case, if he has a "purely imaginary" time response, it should simply be marked as the quadrature reponse. But OP is the only one(?) who can tell us where he got his example from, just so we would not debate over possible cases and diverge from the question. So, OP can help by providing more context.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I mean, it doesn’t really matter where it is coming from. One can just compute it like any other Fourier transform.

Comment: @user110971 True, but the question is double-sided: by forcing you to think of the context it may help you resolve the problem. Maybe this context provides that? Also, I am curious to know about the provenience of the imaginary time response because, honestly, this seems more like a math problem than a signal processing one: throw a formula, dub it time response, perform Fourier.

Comment: The example actually comes from a past exam in my college class. Like you said, have never seen anything with a j in the time domain and was pretty confused too. The textbook didn't help either.

Comment: I can attest to the fact that there are real life applications using complex signals (represented, of course, by pairs of real signals).  For example, in DSP-based radios one generally heterodynes the signal down to zero IF, but in general it won't be symmetric around the carrier.  Representing it in complex form allows one to mathematically differentiate between positive and negative frequency in the baseband signal.

Comment: Is 't' time or some other parametric variable?

Comment: it is time, as it is represented in the time domain of x(t)

Comment: In that case, the FT is real. Factorise the bracket to \$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{t+2}-\frac{1}{t-2}+\frac{1}{t+4}-\frac{1}{t-4}) \$ and look-up FT.

Comment: ... but an imaginary function of time doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jake just remember j is a constant. Treat it as any other constant when taking the Fourier transform.